# Javascript get node innertext based on hierarchy

Tags: javascript, html, xslt, dom

My HTML looks like

```
<li value="0">
 <a href="#">
 <span>DATA TO GET</span><![if gt IE 6]>
 </a><![endif]><!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
 <ul>
 <li value="0">
 <a onclick="return showPane('SomePane',this)" href="#">ACTIVE NODE</a>
 </li>
 </ul>
```

This html is produced using xsl. Now i want to **get the data inside span tag** using javascript. I tried the following:

```
var nameParent =  activeTab.parentNode.parentNode.previousSibling;
window.alert(activeTab.innerHTML);
window.alert(activeTab.parentNode.parentNode.previousSibling.childNode);
```

Here the variable **activeTab** is passed the anchor that contians the text ACTIVE NODE.The first alert gives proper data i.e **ACTIVE NODE** but the second alert says **undefined**.

I think i am travsring the correct path and proper elements. Can some body point out what is wrong here and what else i can do to get the required data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `firstChild` instead of `childNode`:

```
var nameParent =  activeTab.parentNode.parentNode.previousSibling;
window.alert(nameParent.firstChild.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var nameParent =  activeTab.parentNode.parentNode;
window.alert(activeTab.innerHTML);
window.alert(nameParent.parentNode.children[0].children[0].innerHTML);
```

I stronly suggests use jQuery in your Project, it provides methods for easy navigation among dom elements like 
.find() and .children(), .parent for more readable code.

Thanks